# Cube Roles - Restrict data by territory using Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, roles, bids, cubes

I have a cube which I want to restrict users to only be able to access data in their own territory. The territory data could be joined with their user name and a few various tables to  link to my sales territory dimension table. How would I go about using BIDS to create a role that automatically changes the allowed member set per user.

Thanks!
Ethan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link that has a method of doing it: [Cube Roles - Restrict data by territory using Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415281/cube-roles-restrict-data-by-territory-using-active-directory)

At some point in the near future I'll implement and post to see if it works, but I believe it is the answer.

Ethan

Edit:
I have implemented it and it works perfectly, only with one problem. If territories get changed or users get reassigned, the changes won't happen until the cube is reprocessed.
About to ask this as a new question. When making the dll, the analysis server dll is framework 2.0 so make sure that use the target framework 2.0 when you compile it.

Comment: Your link points back to this very question. You have given my brain a Stack Overflow error :).